Converting Image to Gridded Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine
I'm working with Dynamic World data in GEE over a region of Bangladesh.

var roi= ee.FeatureCollection("users/salem043/Bangladesh/CB_with_added_upazila");

var lulc = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1")
 .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
 .select("label");

var lc_16 = lulc
  .filterDate("2016-01-01", "2016-02-28")
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
 .reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());


My goal is to export a CSV object where each row corresponds to a grid cell in lc_16. This requires vectorizing the raster, or converting from an image to a feature collection.
My first attempt to do so using reduceToVectors grouped all adjacent grid-cells with the same image property into one feature. But each feature needs to be its own grid-cell of the same size as in the image.
I tried to readjust, and my newer code gives me uniform columns, but not grids.

// Add pixel coordinates with the appropriate projection
var coordinates = ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(lc_16.projection());

// Compute a truly unique ID for each pixel
var uniquePixels = coordinates.select('x').multiply(1e6) // Scale 'x' to a large number
                              .add(coordinates.select('y')); // Add 'y' to make it unique
uniquePixels = uniquePixels.toInt(); // Cast to integer

// Vectorize the unique ID image to ensure each pixel becomes a separate polygon
var grid = uniquePixels.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  scale: 10, // Ensure this matches your desired resolution
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometry: roi
});

Map.addLayer(grid, {}, "Grid");


Source code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/60f1869a7f9c5fb35c208c4974b88fa7


Your approach produces an image with only three pixels and your obtained result is uniform columns instead grids. You can observe that in your modified code by using 'coveringGrid' method. Result looks as follows:

For producing a grid you need to previously reproject the image with a higher scale. I used 3000 m instead 10 m to speed up the computation by using 'coveringGrid' method instead 'reduceToVectors'. An extract of your modified code looks as follows:
Map.centerObject(geometry);

//LULC classifications subset to ROI
var lulc = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1")
  .filterDate("2016-01-01", "2016-02-28")
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
  .select("label");
  
var test_img = lulc.first();

var proj = test_img.projection();

print(proj.nominalScale());

//Jan 2016-Feb 2016
var lc_16 = lulc
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());

//proj.nominalScale()

lc_16 = lc_16.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 3000);

print(lc_16.projection().nominalScale());
   
var proj_image = lc_16.projection();

var grid_region = roi.geometry().coveringGrid(proj_image);

Map.addLayer(lc_16, imageVisParam, 'img');

Map.addLayer(grid_region);

Map.centerObject(grid_region, 9);

Complete code can be obtained here.
After running the code in the GEE code editor, the result looks as follows. Grid is observed above the Dynamic World data image.

